# I cannot use Image.FromFile because of naming issues in VB.net

Tags: json, vb.net, image

I have a json object that has to use image as a field. I want to use Image.FromFile but the compiler confuses it for the property in the json object. How can I still use the Image.FromFile method without being able to use the value "Image." (image.full is using the json object to retrieve the image name).

```
Public Function returnIcon()
    Return image.FromFile(Path.GetTempPath() + "lolIcons\champions\" + image.full)
End Function
```

Comment: use the fully qualified name: `System.Drawing.Image`

Comment: ... and use Path.Combine to make your path names.

Comment: Thanks. I tried Googling that but came up short. I thought I could use the full name but could not find it.

Comment: Why should I use Path.Combine over my method?

Comment: For the same reason you use `Path.GetTempPath()` and not a hardcoded TEMP path.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code: *(use `System.Drawing.Image` to prevent compiler confusion)*

```
Public Function returnIcon() AS System.Drawing.Image
    Return System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Path.GetTempPath() & "lolIcons\champions\" & image.full)
End Function
```